# Streaming media from AWS to the Web Browser

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-live-streaming, audio-streaming

- I have some large audio files in the S3 bucket.
- I want to play them in a browser on-demand.
- I don't want to firstly download the whole file and only then play it.
- I want to achieve something like YouTube, where the whole video is not immediately downloaded but rather downloaded in small pieces.

Are there any native out-of-the-box solutions provided by AWS? Can a pre-signed S3 URL be used for this purpose? Do I need other services like AWS MediaLive or AWS IVS?

Also, maybe there are advanced JavaScript (browser based) players, that support this type of workflow?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there some reason a simple `<audio>` tag won't work?

Comment: Is it... that simple?

Comment: In its most basic form: yes. The browser is the one deciding that this is an audiofile, therefore to download the first e.g. 2 seconds, start playing it, then keep a buffer of X seconds and download the data from the origin as needed.

Comment: This blew my mind.

Comment: Yep.  I'm sure there are some formats where the browser logic breaks, but for the most part, if you feed it a common format, most browsers will buffer a few minutes of data at a time using byte-range requests.

Comment: This works when you want to stream a predefined file. If you want to stream LIVE , for example a LIVE concert, you can setup CloudFront streaming and set the video / audio feed as origin.